# How to render a view from an action class

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

Let I've written the following action class:

```
class TranAction extends CAction{
    public function run(){
        echo "Hello Yii";
    }
}
```

Now I want to render `myView` view, but I dont know how can I invoke controller's `render()` method from `run()` method?

Comment: Something like this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143865/render-a-view-in-php

Comment: This is something that is covered in the basics of Yii, which is well covered in the documentation, apparently something that you have not taken the time to cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->controller->render('myView');
```